# Vue.js: Add router-link-active to vue-router component loaded for root

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm having some trouble with vue-router. My routes are set up like this:

```js
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: a },
    { path: '/a', component: a },
    { path: '/b', component: b },
    { path: '/c', component: c }
]
```

As you can see, I want to load component `a` when the page loads. But I don't want the URL to change to `/a` when the page loads. However I would like to trigger the `router-link-active`-class on the `<router-link>` related to the `a` component, even though I'm still at `/`.

I've tried with some simple JS like:

```js
if(window.location.hash === '#/') {
    var el = document.querySelector('#drawerList').firstElementChild;
    el.className += 'router-link-active';
}
```

However vue is not removing the class again when I click on the link to `/b` or `/c`. Can any of you hint me in the corrent direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manually bind class to router-link like this

```
<router-link :class="{'router-link-active': $route.fullPath ==='/' || $route.fullPath === '/a'}" to="/a"></router-link>
```

Comment: Wow, that is actually brilliant, and works flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: Best, cleanest answer out there still, thank you!

Comment: This works well but for a little different scenario I am dealing with, is there any way to use wildcards in the conditions? Such as `$route.fullPath === '/user/*'`.

Comment: **EDIT** I used regex to match pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73622296/router-link-active-not-applied-to-matching-routes

Answer (score 6):

The best solution is use "exact" in root url

`<router-link to="/" tag="a" exact>Home</router-link>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `<router-link to="/" exact>`

It prevents active class inclusive match behavior.

Comment: I looked into `exact`, but it didn't work as intended. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

This is my pre-answer - see solution instead.

I ended up doing something custom, rather than seeking a native solution. After looking at a few issues on GitHub, I realised that something like this, stupid as it is - I admit, doesn't exist natively in Vue.js.

My solution: adding an eventlistener that removes itself along with the class, once another link is clicked in the `#drawerMenu`:

HTML structure:

```
<ul id="drawerMenu">
  <li>
    <router-link to="/a">A</router-link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <router-link to="/b">B</router-link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <router-link to="/c">C</router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```js
if(window.location.hash === '#/') {
    var menu = document.querySelector('#drawerMenu');
    var el = menu.firstElementChild.firstChild;
    el.className += 'router-link-active';

    var removeRouterClass = function () {
        el.classList.remove('router-link-active');
        menu.removeEventListener('click', removeRouterClass);
    }

    menu.addEventListener('click', removeRouterClass);
}
```

I hope this helps others like me, and hopefully this will be built into Vue natively at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a use-case when I needed to have an active class whenever 1 of the following is true:

- `/users`
- `/users/1/edit`
- `/users/1/view`

using `vuejs 3` in main `app.vue` I have routes defined. The routes are then parameter-injected into `sidemenu component` (which is not important in this example)

`app.vue` dependencies

```
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
```

`setup()` method (using `composition API`):

```
setup() {
const route = useRoute();

const myActiveClass = ref(null);

const checkIfMustActivateRoute = () => {
  return {
    active:
      window.location.pathname.startsWith("/users/view/") ||
      window.location.pathname.startsWith("/users/edit/"),
  };
};

watch(
  () => route.fullPath,
  async (_) => {
    myActiveClass.value = checkIfMustActivateRoute();
  }
);

myActiveClass.value = checkIfMustActivateRoute();

const routes = ref([
  { id: 0, name: "Home", href: "/", icon: "fas fa-home" },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Users",
    href: "/users",
    icon: "far fa-clone",
    class: myActiveClass,
  },
]);

return {
  routes,
};
},
```

`NavLink`s are dynamically generated like so:

```
  <li v-for="tab of routes" :key="tab.id" class="nav-item">
    <router-link :to="tab.href" class="nav-link" :class="tab.class">
      <div class="align-items-center">
        <span class="nav-link-icon"><i :class="tab.icon"></i></span>
        <span class="nav-link-text ms-3">{{ tab.name }}</span>
      </div>
    </router-link>
  </li>
```

Now whenever the router's path property changes I trigger the active class update function. This way we don't have to use aliases or any other trickery.

The result is - for all 3 paths I always enable `active` class.

Answer (score 0):

use could use `exact-active-class` on your router-link element.
Note: `desiredClass` is the class you want to apply if the URL matches the router-link's `to` attribute.

```
<router-link to="/about" exact-active-class="desiredClass">About</router-link>
```